# DDD One to Many with many properties to single id of father

Tags: c#, .net-core, domain-driven-design, .net-5

it is the question for DDD experienced people.
If we have one child entity which has two properties but both are FK of father item, what would be the best approach to design the entity of child ?
Example, we have user entity, and than you have Company entity with two properties which declare ManagerId and DirectorId both should be FK of Id of User entity.

Would be this code good practice ?

```
public class User: IAggregateRoot 
{
      public int Id {get; private set;}
      public string Name {get;private set;}
      private readonly List<Company> _directorCompanies = new List<Company>();
      public List<Company> DirectorCompanies => _directorCompanies.AsReadOnly();
      private readonly List<Company> _managerCompanies = new List<Company>();
      public List<Company> ManagerCompanies => _managerCompanies.AsReadOnly();
      public User(string name)
      {
        Name = name
      }
} 
public class Company: IAggregateRoot
{
  public int Id {get;private set;}
  public string Name {get;private set;}
  public int DirectorId {get;private set;}
  public int? ManagerId {get;private set;}
  public User Director {get;private set;}
  public User Manager {get;private set;}
  public Company(string name, int directorId, int? manangerid)
  {
    Name = name;
    DirectorId = directorId;
    ManagerId = managerId;
  }
}
```

With this solution later I can take Name on for specific company who is Director and who is Manager if there is any. Otherwise if I manage like this:

```
 public class User: IAggregateRoot 
    {
          public int Id {get; private set;}
          public string Name {get;private set;}
          public User(string name)
          {
            Name = name
          }
    } 
    public class Company: IAggregateRoot
    {
      public int Id {get;private set;}
      public string Name {get;private set;}
      public int DirectorId {get;private set;}
      public int? ManagerId {get;private set;}

      public Company(string name, int directorId, int? manangerid)
      {
        Name = name;
        DirectorId = directorId;
        ManagerId = managerId;
      }
    }
```

How I can get the name with `include` in repository ?
My concern is what would be correct way, good way, to implement this situation where I can get info of Director or Manager if need it.
Regards,

Comment: There isn't an answerable question here.  The closest thing to a question is "how can I get the name with include in repository," and I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: If you just want to combine company and user objects there are easy object-oriented ways to do that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey let say with my question "how can I get the name with include in repository" I had mean if with repository pattern I call, example: `_unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.SelectList(includes:"${nameOf("Director")}")`, something like this.

Comment: I would start with ordinary object-orientation here.  Forget about DDD for a moment (it's a design technique, not a coding technique), and just focus on how you would combine your classes in a way that produces your desired results.

Comment: Let say to design on way where we will have single entity for following UserDirector and single entity to follow ManagerDirector. So UserDirector would be UserId and CompanyID, as many to many relationship.

Comment: OK.  Does that provide the functionality you need?

Comment: Yes. But would be that correct way and cleaner way, or maybe to listen the answer from bellow or something else ? I want to have good and clean functionality, sometimes if something is working for me doesn't meant that is good way, which later can create me a head pains.

Comment: You need more experience in ordinary object-orientation before you become concerned about "correctness."

Comment: Any recommendation about ordinary object-orientation ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is understanding the basics of OO programming,

```
public class User: IAggregateRoot 
{
      public int Id {get; private set;}
      public string Name {get;private set;}
      private readonly List<Company> _directorCompanies = new List<Company>();
      public List<Company> DirectorCompanies => _directorCompanies.AsReadOnly();
      private readonly List<Company> _managerCompanies = new List<Company>();
      public List<Company> ManagerCompanies => _managerCompanies.AsReadOnly();
      public User(string name)
      {
        Name = name
      }
}
```

This `_directorCompanies` and `_managerCompanies` don't make much sense given that a user **can** be a manager, a manager **has** to be a user, but no all user **will** be managers or directors. The way I think this design is:

```
public class User: IAggregateRoot 
{
      public int Id {get; private set;}
      public string Name {get;private set;}
} 

public class Company: IAggregateRoot
{
  public int Id {get;private set;}
  public string Name {get;private set;}
  public int DirectorId {get;private set;}
  public int? ManagerId {get;private set;}
  public virtual User Director {get;private set;}
  public virtual User Manager {get;private set;}  
}
```

Is something that you showed, but following the OO way of thinking.

For the query, an example:

**Users that are managers**:

```
myContext.Users.Where(c => myContext.Managers.Contains(m => c.Id));
```